# Powershell - Get-aduser -filter EmailAddress

Tags: powershell

I'm struggling with getting the SamAccountName from AD by searching with the email address. I have a CSV that contains email addresses but need to get the SamAccountName. "write-host $user.EmailAddress" prints the email address correctly, Get-ADuser is not giving any errors but "write-host $CurrentUser" prints an empty line

```
foreach($user in $users)
{
write-host $user.EmailAddress
    #$CurrentUser = Get-ADUser -filter "EmailAddress -eq '$($user)'"
    #$CurrentUser = Get-aduser -Filter { "mail -eq '$($user.EmailAddress)'"} -Properties mail
    $CurrentUser = Get-ADUser -Filter { mail -eq "$($user.EmailAddress)"} -properties SamAccountName
    write-host $CurrentUser
```

I've tried a few different snippets I found online but just can't get it to work

Powershell version: 5

Comment: if you manually run `Get-ADUser` with just _one_ entry from the `$Users` list, does it work?

Comment: The syntax `-Filter "property -operator 'value'"` always works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give yourself a break on the black magic of active directory filters.  Trying to get the quoting right for "$object.property" is just too much trouble.  The truth is, it's trial and error, and no one understands how it works.  The type of -filter isn't even scriptblock but string, but even the docs seem to expect you to pass it as scriptblock.  See the Backus-Naur form under -Filter in the docs.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps

```
$emailaddress = $user.emailaddress
get-aduser -filter { mail -eq $emailaddress }
```

Comment: Agree! have faced the string vs ScriptBlock issue before.

Comment: I think it was just one of those days yesterday, even when trying the suggestions from you guys on here I just could not get it to work, I started again today from scratch and in less than 10 minutes had it working. I appreciate all the help from everyone

Comment: ###Just Remember - with 'Gmailified' Email, and Cloud Mail, the record is different###
    $emailaddress = $user.emailaddress
    get-aduser -filter { msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute1 -eq $emailaddress }